# Jmeter JSON Extractor (Post Processor) removes the double quotes " "

Tags: json, jmeter

I searched on this site and mostly the questions are around JSON Path Extractor, not the native JSON Extractor Post Processor.

Using JMeter 5.1.1 , I am hitting https://reqres.in//api/users?page=2 
which will return me JSON response

```
    {
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 3,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Eve",
            "last_name": "Holt",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "email": "charles.morris@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Morris",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "email": "tracey.ramos@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Tracey",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this JSON Extractor

[image]

I get

[image]

As we can see , JSON Extractor removes the double quotes , so instead having `"eve.holt@reqres.in"` , we get `eve.holt@reqres.in` .

Is there any way to keep the double quotes using JSON extractor ?  I need to have the double quotes `"eve.holt@reqres.in"` .  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, no way to keep the double quotes when you using JSON extractor, exception you edit plugin JSON extractor. Or you can use JSR223 PostProcessor like that
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This solution seems to be the quick workaround solution for someone not that fluent at regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all data using `$.data[0]`

After it add Regular Expression Extractor using your JMeter variable as `email` and create a new variable using the following regex

```
email":"([^"]+)"
```

Template `$1$` and Match No. 1

Then your value with quotes will be available using `${email_g0}`